# Unable to get the response from Jquery ajax using ajaxoptions

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to pass jQuery

```
function getData(Id) {
    var ajaxOptions = {
        url: 'Api/Client/Get?Id=' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done().fail(error);
}
```

When I tried to call the function `getData()` I'm not able to see the record. Please let me know how can I get the record.

Comment: there is no success handler registered.. also what is `error`

Comment: you need to do something with the returned data in the `.done()` callback

Comment: I am not getting any error.iam not able to see the response in the output.Event though I add the fowllowing code it is not giving me the record output. return $.ajax(ajaxOptions).done(function(data)).fail(error);

Answer (score 1):

Try this and look at the console if you see any output

**EDIT**

```
function getData(Id) {
    var ajaxOptions = {
        url: 'Api/Client/Get?Id=' + id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json'
    };

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions)
        .done(function(data){
            var myData = eval(data);
            for(var i=0; i < myData.length; i++){
                console.log("MyAttributeName = " + myData[i].myAttributeName);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hi,I am able to get the response in the data.But not able to get data when tried to call the function Example: var data=getData(2);In the data variable I am not able to see the response.

Comment: I have edited my post you need to change ´data = getData(2)` by `var myData = eval(data);`Look at my post

Comment: Even I am able to get the value inside the done().but outside I am not able to get the response.When I try to call the function getData(2),the response did not include me the record data